# Text to columns on paste

Tags: microsoft-excel

**The Goal**

First of all, here's what I'm attempting to do.  I have a sheet which has some editable columns say, A1-A10.  Cells A11-A20 are all calculated cells and I want them hidden and protected.  When I paste in data from my external source, it comes in as CSV. When I paste in data into my protected sheets, I want this data to split on comma across the available cells A1-A10.

**The Problem**

With the sheet protected, TextToColumns is disabled, and thus pasting in my data doesn't split on my comma delimiter because the default delimiter is a tab.

**What I've Tried**

1. I've attempted to use the VBA function TextToColumns, but that is not allowed on protected sheets
2. I've created a button on an existing unprotected "readme" sheet that would set the delimiter to comma and perform the split on a dummy cell hoping that this would carry over using the comma as a delimiter when pasting data into subsequent pages, but this didn't work.  The pasted text came in as the full csv line, not separated.
3. I've manually performed the TextToColumns trick in #2 by clicking the TextToColumns button in the ribbon bar.  This does work, but I'd rather not have to do this manual step every time.

**The Question**

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?  Can I set my default delimiter in Excel to be a comma?  Looking for some advice on this, or worst case scenario, am I stuck doing the manual process in step 3?

**Note**

Why can't I just unprotect the sheet? I want it protected so that if I accidentally grab too many columns from my source and paste it into the sheet, it doesn't overwrite any of my calculation fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can unprotect the sheet within your VBA macro just before the TextToColumns call and re-protect it afterwards:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveRange.TextToColumns ...
ActiveSheet.Protect ...
```

Note that the only parameter for the Worksheet.Unprotect method is an optional password, only necessary if the worksheet is protected with a password (personally, I never bother with a password).

Worksheet.Protect() has parameters for all of the protection options, so you'll need to choose what actions (if any) you want to be able to do on the worksheet afterwards; see [Worksheet Protect documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect)

To avoid overwriting your calculation fields, however, it's probably safest to open your csv file in a new workbook and just copy and paste the desired columns into your formula worksheet (don't forget to close the temp workbook).

If, however, you can guarantee there are no more than a fixed number of columns you can use FieldInfo to suppress anything after the 10th column (using `FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlGeneralFormat), Array(2, xlGeneralFormat), ... Array(9, xlTextFormat), Array(!0, xlGeneralFormat), Array(11, xlSkipColumn), Array(12, xlSkipColumn))` but if there are more columns than you suppress with xlSkipColumn they'll get parsed and overwrite your formulas.